# Steps in changing theme of sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using Version 6.5.16 (Build 1082) of community edition sugarcrm, I will need to change the current theme without purchasing it, may i know the steps of changing the theme ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom theme using theme framework of SugarCrm.

Please check the developer guide 
http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework/Themes